# iOS Left menu by button using MMDrawerController

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, mmdrawercontroller

I got some troubles making button for open/close leftside menu.

I made a button, but I can not configure it correctly, because I can't recognize whether the left view is open. It can be opened by swipe(special MMDrawer method), so I can't use a regular BOOL variable lika 'isOpen'. Also, I find it difficult to find a property for left view status (open/close).

I was surprised, that noone had trouble like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the [`openSide`](https://github.com/mutualmobile/MMDrawerController/blob/master/MMDrawerController/MMDrawerController.h#L173) property of `MMDrawerController`.

> The current open side of the drawer.
>
> Note this value will change as soon as a pan gesture opens a drawer, or when a open/close animation is finished.

As soon as the left view is opened, the value should change to `MMDrawerSideLeft`.